# Dereferencing a pointer while passing to a reference expecting function creates a copy, why?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, dereference

Consider a simple example

```
template<class InputIterator,class InputIterator2, class OutputIterT, class Function, class T2>
    OutputIterT foo(InputIterator first, InputIterator2 last, OutputIterT result, Function fn, const T2& x)
  {
    while (first!=last) {
     *result=fn(*first,x);
      ++first;
    }
    return result;
}
```

where the Function fn that is passed is

```
template<class T, class V>
 T fn(const T& a, const V& b) {
   return std::make_pair(a.first, a.second *b);
}
```

When I use this code and check for the constructors being called, I see that at each call fn(*first,x), the copy constructor is being called. I find this hard to understand, as the function parameter is a reference. Please note that the iterators being used, are map iterators. To avoid the unnecessary copy I changed the code to accept the iterator directly (fn function), so that the line now is

```
*result=fn(first,x);
```

and the fn is

```
template<class Iter, class V>
 T fn(Iter a, const V& b) {
   return std::make_pair(a->first, a->second *b);
}
```

#### Question

Why is the copy being created in the first case, with the call to fn? When can this happen? Why does it happen, even though the function parameter is a const reference? Thank you for helping me understand.

To clarify, the copy constructor of the

```
(*first).second
```

is being called, before entering the function fn.

### Answer

@IgorTandetnik provided the correct answer in the comments bellow, and @SebastianRedl  provided further rational on why this happens.

The map object of the type

```
map<Key,Value>;
```

is really

```
map<Key const,Value>;
```

even if the programmer does not specify it as such (if you omit the const).

Now, when instantiating the foo function, if you (as I did) provide the pair type as

```
pair<Key,Value>
```

this does not match the pairs contained in the map, which are

```
pair<Key const, Value>
```

(again, even if you did not explicitly say key should be const). This causes a need for conversion as when passing to the function fn.

Thank you both!

Comment: The copy constructor of *what* is being called? I suggest you show a [mcve]

Comment: This looks interesting. Please add a [mcve] it is very hard to reason about in its current form.

Comment: I will try to replicate the exact behavior on a minimal example, as suggested.  The code comes from a project with large objects. Will report back very soon.

Comment: `std::make_pair(a.first, a.second *b)` would make a copy of `a.first`, and possibly of `a.second` and/or `b` depending on what `*` means there.

Comment: Also, although incidental to the issue you perceive, the contents of *result are rewritten during each iteration of the while loop, so it looks like a lot of computation is wasted --- *result end up just being fn(--last,x), barring edge cases.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The copy constructor of the a is called, that is, before the function fn is entered, the copy constructor of *first, is being called.

Comment: @jwimberley No, elements are being added to the collection. In the end, the final iterator is being returned in case the client needs it.

Comment: I doubt it. You are likely mis-interpreting your observations. MCVE would help.

Comment: Does `fn` accept `std::pair<Key, Value>`, by any chance? If you are iterating over `std::map<Key, Value>`, `*first` is of type `std::pair<const Key, Value>` - a different type, so an implicit conversion is performed.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You are right, it told it wrong. The copy constructor of first->second is being called, as *first is being passed as an argument. I am woring on MCVE.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It accepts std::pair<T*,T>. So your point could be valid.

Comment: But the iterator's value is likely of type `std::pair<T* const, T>`, necessitating a conversion.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Please provide a longer description of why and how, and I will accept. You seem to be correct. Thank you!

Comment: @LeastSquaresWonderer I am fairly sure that the intermediate values of *result are unusued, but perhaps this is just an artifact of a simplification you have made

Comment: Why and how what? I'm not sure I understand your request.

Comment: Sorry. Your point seems valid, and I will look into it right now. The map type is defined to be std::map<T*,T> and not std::map<T* const,T>, but perhaps something to this effect is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: The key type of a `std::map` is `const` whether the template parameter is or not. This is so that you cannot change keys that are already in the map, which could change the way they compare and thus corrupt the map's internal structure.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Thank you.  You and Igor answered my question. Please, one of you, provide an answer, so I can accept and close this question. Again, thank you very much, I did not know that the key is always const.

Answer (score 1):

I think the copy is made in `std::make_pair()` method, which returns a reference to a new object composed of two instances of the class T and V that are copied from `a->first` and  `a->second *b`. Else, modifying anything in the returned pair would also modify the object you passed by reference in `fn()`.

edit: now you have given more information, I think the copy constructor of (*first).second is called when you are performing : `a->second *b`. As I don't know how is overloaded your operator *, I guess it implies a copy.

Comment: The operator is overloaded with a const referece for lhs and rhs, aswell for rvalue references. The copy constructor is being called before entering the fn.